# Deezer SDK IOS play track by id

Tags: ios, swift, api, sdk, deezer

The [official examples of Deezer's api in swift](https://github.com/deezer/iOS-sdk-samples) show us a method called `getObject` in the `DeezerManager`.

```swift
func getObject(identifier: String, callback: @escaping (_ object: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    DZRObject.object(withIdentifier: identifier, requestManager: DZRRequestManager.default(), callback: callback)
}
```

I want to play a track with id 533609232 (Drake - God's Plan).
To do it, I need to have the `DZRTrack`/`DZRObject`. So I called:

```swift
DZRObject.object(withIdentifier: "533609232", requestManager: DZRRequestManager.default(), callback: { (data, error) in
    print(data, error)
    //player stuff
})
```

But I've got an error `NSException`:

```
2019-05-02 22:50:23.845973+0200 my-app[51762:1318493] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010af7d6fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109dd2ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aecbddc _CFThrowFormattedException + 194
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010af5786d -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 237
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010af6c2a4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
    5   my-app                              0x0000000106af3ef5 +[DZRObject infoURLWithBaseURL:identifier:] + 134
    6   my-app                              0x0000000106af4062 +[DZRObject objectWithRequestManager:baseURL:identifier:callback:] + 123
    7   my-app                              0x0000000106af3fb3 +[DZRObject objectWithIdentifier:requestManager:callback:] + 80
    8   my-app                              0x00000001069cd93d $s10my_app30DeezerViewControllerC5testayyF + 461
    9   my-app                              0x00000001069cf75e $s10my_app30DeezerViewControllerC0C6ActionyyF + 46
    10  my-app                              0x00000001069cf794 $s10my_app30DeezerViewControllerC0C6ActionyyFTo + 36
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000010fd73204 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000010f7c8c19 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    13  UIKitCore                           0x000000010f7c8f36 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    14  UIKitCore                           0x000000010f7c7eec -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 583
    15  UIKitCore                           0x000000010fdabeee -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2547
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000010fdad5d2 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4079
    17  UIKitCore                           0x000000010fd8bd16 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
    18  UIKitCore                           0x000000010fe5c293 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3232
    19  UIKitCore                           0x000000010fe5ebb9 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5911
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aee4be1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aee4463 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aedeb1f __CFRunLoopRun + 1231
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aede302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001136072fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    25  UIKitCore                           0x000000010fd71ba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    26  my-app                              0x00000001068d4ebb main + 75
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cfc9541 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

So I don't understand why I got this error.
Am I doing wrong? Is it an other way to do it?

Comment: It would probably help if you could share the stack trace that's printed in the console after the exception.

Comment: @amadour thanks for editing and answering, I've updated the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the Deezer SDK documentation (`DZRObject.h`)

> You should not call this method directly on the DZRObject class but on one
>    of its concrete subclass (e.g. DZRUser, DZRTrack, DZRArtist, ...)

Maybe try `DZRTrack.object(withIdentifier...` instead?

Comment: It works ! Wow it was so easy ! Thanks a lot for helping (.. an idiot question hahaha) !